# Biggest spots in c# matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, object, logic

I need ideas how to make this happen. I just started to learn programming. I need to make a program which generates random spots (marked by * chars) in matrix filled by . chars. Matrix size is entered in console (int n and int m). I managed to do this part. But the hard part is - I have to find the number of spots (* and every * near it combines to one big spot) and  the biggest of the spots. How could I do this?

Thank you very much...
[here's how matrix looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkMps.png) in this scenario - number of spots should be 6 and biggest spot size is 21

Comment: Lookup [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate 3 random numbers. First number will be the first index of the matrix, the second number -- the second index in the matrix, and the third number of iterations of the above 2 actions. Use the System.Random class and the method of this class yourobject.Next(). The constructor for this class has two overloads. One overload is empty. It generates a seed depending of the time (be careful with the time!!! Don't initialize objects inside a loop). Another overload is using a seed given by you. The static method Next() was also two overloads. One is empty. It generates an random number, and nothing more. The second overload, you need to specify the maximum number. The numbers that will be generated will be in this length 
0 < n < yournumber. In your case to generate the index you need to specify as a parameter the Length of the matrix + 1, but the result will need to be: result - 1 (I think you will understand why). Good luck!